# Select 2 not selected option

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I took a ready-made working example 
[working example][1]
and remade it to fit my needs.
[my code][2]
But I do not have the selected item.

```
  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/tw57m8bx/1/
  [2]: http://jsfiddle.net/vipTelnet/m7vx0nuc/2/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source of the fiddle, you will notice that the versions of select2 library resource is different.

> Version 3.5.2 : http://jsfiddle.net/tw57m8bx/1/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.js"></script>
```

> Version 4.0.5 : http://jsfiddle.net/vipTelnet/m7vx0nuc/2/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
```

**Update:** Making it work on version 4.0.5

Working fiddle > http://jsfiddle.net/m7vx0nuc/3/

You need to bind data by adding data attribute to `select2()`. Also added default empty `option` tag in HTML, else first element is selected by default.

```
$('#select').select2({
   minimumInputLength: 0,
   data:lastOptions
});
```

Comment: The question was just how to make this code work on version 4.0.5

Comment: Updated the answer. Check it.